# AWS Lambda DNS provisioning

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I see that from my lambda that it sends requests to "169.254.78.1" regardless of what the provisioned Domain name servers in the DHCP options associated to the VPC.
Is this expected. If I run a lambda function and read the /etc/resolv.conf, I see that it "169.254.78.1" and a commented line indicating the DHCP provisioned IP for DNS as "configured nameserver".

```
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
; configured nameserver 111.111.111.111
nameserver 169.254.78.1
```

Is this expected? Is "169.254.78.1" VIP of some sort that directs traffic to the configured nameservers?

Answer (score 1):

These are most likely link-local addresses in AWS's reserved 169.254.0.0/16 network.

You might be familiar with this network if you used instance metadata: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

Comment: Isn't that for an EC2 host? I am running from a AWS lambda function. I get that all the functions are running on a lambda host but I'm curious how the provisioning or traffic redirection works.

Comment: Underlying environment still needs to run in some sort VPC, and 169.154.0.0/16 seems to be universally used